# Using NativeWind With React Native Paper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I am using [native wind](https://www.nativewind.dev/quick-starts/expo) and [react native paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/index.html) with typescript. I would like to add "className" and "tw" attributes to my paper views.

I've already added it on my other views using declares like this:

```
import "react-native";

declare module "react-native" {
  interface FlatListProps<ItemT> extends VirtualizedListProps<ItemT> {
    className?: string;
    tw?: string;
  }
}
```

and my views have "className" and "tw", but for paper views this does not work:

```
import "react-native-paper"

declare module "react-native-paper" {
    interface FABProps {
        className? : string;
        tw?: string;
    }
}
```

and my FAB view still does not have "className" or "tw"

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `styled` to style any component:

```
...
import { styled } from "nativewind";
import { FAB } from "react-native-paper";

const StyledFAB = styled(FAB);

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <StyledFAB
        icon="plus"
        className="absolute right-0 bottom-0 m-4"
        onPress={() => console.log("Pressed")}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```